# react native global variable

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, global-variables

i am very knew to react native, our app was created in cordova, and we are switching to react native. my app needs to scan for ble devices while the app is in forground. after authentication with server and pulling the ble devices you are allowed to scan, the app starts scanning for these devices, and every time the phone detects a new UUID i need to store it in a variable that does not rerender any component, because the data might change every 100 millisecond, and it is not relative to any UI to be displayed, i only want the data in memory. these data are for analyzing only, and i need it to be accessible anywhere in app, for example after an onPress event, see what is the current Devices i hold in memory.

my solution was in App.js the root component of my app, i created a variable:

```
global.LiveData = {}
```

i have a Home.js component holding all the screens of the app and is rendered after authentication. i start ble scanning on the first render of the component in a UseEffect hook. whenever i detect a device that belongs to the user i set it in global.LiveData like this

```
global.LiveData[nearbyDevice.PrimaryDeviceID] = {...nearbyDevice};
```

and if the device is for the user, and is set to be seen, i push to redux the device name to be rendered in a component.

is this a good practice, or it might create issues?

how can i have a better solution that the one i did?